# How to import previous order history in bigcommerce website?

Tags: bigcommerce

I have a website hosted on bigcommerce. I want to import my previous order history in bigcommerce, so that my previous orders related to all customers will be displayed on bigcommerce dashboard. How to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

This is relatively difficult to do because of the nature of orders and the fact that they use customer data as well as product data.

You can accomplish this by ["injecting" orders through the API](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/orders), but it would be optimal to have customer data in first then product data. The orders would need to be mapped to the product IDs in Bigcommerce which requires additional data massaging/transformation.

Comment: I want to import my csv file into orders section in bigcommerce....so when we click on orders it display all orders including new and previous orders history

Comment: There is no CSV import for orders to BigCommerce for many of the same reasons I described above (complexity). You could use a script to read the data from the CSV and hit the API, but it then faces the issues detailed above.